# How to position a commandbar where I want it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button on a userform in Excel. When the user clicks on the button, a command bar pops up, however this command bar only pops up where the user's mouse is. I want the command bar to always pop up in a particular position (under the button the user clicked) regardless of the mouse position. Any ideas?  My current code is below. Thank you

I tried using the Commandbar.position property, but get the following error: "Method 'Position' of object 'CommandBar' failed Procedure CreateShortcut"

```
Public Sub CreatePopUp(menuOptions As Object)
Dim myBar As CommandBar
Dim myItem As CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next

CommandBars("MyShortcut").Delete

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set myBar = CommandBars.Add _
   (name:="MyShortcut", Position:=msoBarPopup, Temporary:=True)

For Each opt In menuOptions.Keys
    Set myItem = myBar.controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    With myItem
        .caption = menuOptions(opt)(0)
        .OnAction = opt
        .faceId = menuOptions(opt)(1)
    End With
Next


'CommandBars("MyShortcut").ShowPopup
```

Comment: Does `myBar` have a `Top` and a `Left` property?

Comment: It does, but has no effect. I think the CommandBars.ShowPopup is driving the actual action

Comment: Have you tried setting the top and left values *after* invoking ShowPopUp?

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to show the answer to this, which was way easier than I thought! The ShowPopup method will default to the mouse location if an x and y parameters aren't given. All you have to do is specify your location like: .ShowPopup x,y.